# Is it OK to ask other users to upvote?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I was browsing StackExchange and saw this highly voted answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82610/52911

It had the following content:

> Even more bonus!! Run this snippet to *automatically* run the program,
>   upvote, and run again! (Requires rep > 15, auth). If it doesn't work,
>   please tell me.
>
> ```js
>  
>  function f(){
>    $.get("//api.stackexchange.com/posts/82610?site=codegolf",d=>alert(d.items[0].score));
>  }
>  
>  function g(){
>    $.get("//api.stackexchange.com/upvote/82610?site=codegolf",d=>alert(d)));
>  }
>  
>  f();
>  g();
>  f();
> ```
>
> ```html
>  
>  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

The user is clearly asking users to test his code and getting them to upvote his post. The post already has 30 votes.

Should this be allowed?

UPDATE: The user has removed the code. But I still need to know if it is allowed.

Comment: Generally speaking? Not OK. But each site got its own set of rules and culture. This might be proper on that specific site, so this question better be posted in their per-site meta

Comment: It seems to me that the second-best way to attract downvotes is to ask for upvotes. (The best way, of course, is to ask for downvotes.)

Answer (score 6):

Usually I would say no, but let's take a closer look at the context...

This code and text is posted as part of a contest on PPCG. The contest is named *Stack Exchange Vote Counter*. How would you check if the answer given is correct? Yes, by voting on a post.

Of course, the author is 'smart' to use his own post to 'test' this. Is that really bad? No, just funny. He could have use a Sandbox post, that would be the best option, but I can't see misbehavior by this answer.